# Proof Verification: Prove that HxK is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Assume that H & K are groups with identity elements $e_h$ & $e_k$ respectively.

Let $\Bbb{H}\times\Bbb{K}$:={$(h,k):h\in \Bbb{H}, k\in\Bbb{K}$}

and operation of the set is defined as $(h_1,k_1)(h_2,k_2)$:=$(h_1h_2, k_1k_2)$, $\forall h_1,h_2\in \Bbb{H}, k_1,k_2\in\Bbb{K}$.
Prove that $\Bbb{H}\times\Bbb{K}$ is a group.

Proof:

(closure) Let $(a,b)(c,d)\in\Bbb{H}\times\Bbb{K}$ such that $a,c\in\Bbb{H}$ and $b,d\in\Bbb{K}$. Then $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,bd)$ and since $\Bbb{H}$ & $\Bbb{K}$ are groups then there is closure under its binary operation. Hence, $ac\in\Bbb{H}$ and $bd\in\Bbb{K}$ and $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,bd)\in\Bbb{H}\times\Bbb{K}$.

(existence of identity) Since $e_h\in\Bbb{H}$ and $e_k\in\Bbb{K}$ then by definition of $\Bbb{H}\times\Bbb{K}$ $(e_h,e_k)\in\Bbb{H}\times\Bbb{K}$. This shows, $(a,b)(e_h,e_k)=(a,b)\in\Bbb{H}\times\Bbb{K}$ and $(e_h,e_k)(a,b)=(e_ha, e_kb)=(ae_h,be_k)=(a,b)(e_h,e_k)$.

(existence of inverse) Since $a\in\Bbb{H}$ and $b\in\Bbb{K}$ then since $\Bbb{H}$ and $\Bbb{K}$ are groups $a^{-1}\in\Bbb{H}$ and $b^{-1}\in\Bbb{K}$ which implies $(a^{-1},b^{-1})\in\Bbb{H}\times\Bbb{K}$, $\forall a\in \Bbb{H}, b\in \Bbb{K}$. This shows, $(a,b)(a^{-1},b^{-1})=(e_h,e_k)\in\Bbb{H}\times\Bbb{K}$ and $(a,b)(a^{-1},b^{-1})=(aa^{-1},bb^{-1})=(a^{-1}a,b^{-1}b)=(a^{-1},b^{-1})(a,b)=(e_h,e_k)$

(Associativity) $[(a,b)(c,d)](g,f)=(acg,bdf)=(a,b)[(cg,df)]=(a,b)[(c,d)(g,f)]$.
$\bullet$

Comment: You need to show that $(e_h, e_k)$ satisfies the property of an identity element. And similarly, $(a,b)^ {-1}=(a^{-1}, b^{-1})$. And where is associativity?

Comment: edited. is it now correct?

Comment: Well, technically you need to show $(e_h,e_k)(a,b)=(a,b)$ and $(a^{-1},b^{-1})(a,b)=(e_h,e_k)$ also (but I guess you got that part already!). *Associativity is still missing*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to check associativity. Also, in the existence of identity, you should also prove that the element $(e_{h},e_{k})$ is indeed the identity for the binary operation in the cartesian product. And the same for the inverse, you should check that it is indeed the inverse.

I didn't know this type of post ("proof verification"), I hope this was what I was expected to answer.

Comment: I've edited the post. Is that correct?

Comment: Not quite yet. If the groups are not abelian, you need to show that the identity is a two sided identity, and similarly that the inverse is a two sided inverse. And associativity is still missing. You have to check: a(bc)=(ab)c (where each letter is a pair in your case)

Comment: I think this is it?

Comment: Yes. If you wonder why this "two sided" property is important you can think of any infinite set and the set of injective functions from that set to itself. It is not a group and the only axiom which breaks is that we don't have two sided inverses (only inverses on the left!): if the image of $f$ is not the whole set, then no matter what you compose $f$ with on the right, the image of the composition will always be that of $f$ at most (hence not all of your set) and therefore the composition cannot be the identity on that set.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out! I have never given that any thought before.

Comment: why would the image of $f$ be not the whole set if we have only one sided inverses?

Comment: Think of the integers as a set if you want and "multiplication by 2" as $f$. The image of $f$ is just the even integers. If you precompose it with any other function $g$, the composition has as image the image under $f$ of the image under $g$ of the integers. And as we have just said, this is going to be a subset of the even integers, hence not all the integers.

Comment: and that would imply that the inverse is one sided?

Comment: Yes, that shows that you cannot find an inverse on the right for some injective functions. But actually after thinking about it I see that there are also no left sided inverses, as their left inverse among all the set theoretic maps is not injective (hence not in our group). In any case you can try to come up with working examples yourself, it is a good exercise